# How to get a data field in gridview to become a url

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database, gridview

Again, I know this has been answered many a time, but I'm getting confused with all the examples. So I'll ask it in the way I need answered.

I have a sql table, `supplylinks`. this has `rowid` (identity pk), `title` (varchar), `link` (varchar) and `description` (varchar).

The link field is an actual hyperlink, a url.
So for arguments sake, lets say the first row is:

> 1 | Google | http://www.google.com | Google Search engine

Easy enough.
Now I'm loading this into a gridview.
Nothing fancy, all done in c# code.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=DEV6\MSSQLHOSTING;Database=Intranet;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        ds = new DataSet("ds");
        if (type.Equals("SAIX"))
        {

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select [Title],[Link],[Description] from SupplierLinks where SuppRowID = " + index, conn);
            da.Fill(ds);
        }
        if (type.Equals("Domian Related Links"))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select [Title],[Link],[Description] from DomainLinks where SuppRowID = " + index, conn);
            da.Fill(ds);
        }
        if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                grdLinks.DataSource = ds;

                grdLinks.DataBind();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lblDisp.Text = "";
            lblError.Text = "There are no links for that type";
        }
```

Nothing wrong there. I get my info. But I want to now make the link that is returned by the sql table and put into the gridview as a proper link so that when someone clicks on the link, they are redirected to Google, in this instance.

Please help. All other coding around here is confusing me. Lots are saying I must add a hyperlink column to the gridview. But where?

I was getting so far, then got lost as to what to bind.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdLinks" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="col2" 
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Like I said, I'm lost and confused.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all I needed was

```
<a href='<%# Eval("Link") %>'>
                <asp:Label ID="LinkLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Link") %>' /></a>
```

in my listview.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Columns>
    <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="LeadID" DataNavigateUrlFields="LeadID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="LeadInformation.aspx?LeadID={0}" Text="Lead ID" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="DateTime" HeaderText="Date Updated" />
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Bind("LeadID") + Request.QueryString("type") %>' Text=""></asp:HyperLink>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: nope. this was the post that confused me to no end. don't know what to put and where. sorry

Comment: what exactly confusing here? just a matter of adding a template field and do the binding. have you done the gridview binding correctly before displaying a link inside the GridView?

Comment: its the querystring. I don't know what I must put there, if at all. and this seems to add a new column. I want to adjust the current column and make it a hyperlink. can this be done programmatically? dynamically?